# How to use getpivotdata when pivot table datafield has a subheader

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to use getpivotdata to copy certain specific pivot table data to the data sheet. I am able to do it if there are no subheaders. However when there are subheaders i run into problems running the code.

i've tried many different methods but to no avail please help. I believe that i'm missing out something in the bracket for getpivotdata. Please take a look at the code

[Error i get from Damian's Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw2GI.png)

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z7Ce.png)

[Picture of Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVwwx.png)

It works when i don't include the subheader.

```
Dim PT As PivotTable

    Set PT = Sheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable2")

    Range("C28").Value = PT.GetPivotData("Profit", "Region", "2", "Department", "107").Value
```

It doesn't work when i include the subheader as shown below. It will give me error 1004 (Application Defined or Object Defined Error)

```
Dim PT As PivotTable

    Set PT = Sheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable2")

    Range("C28").Value = PT.GetPivotData("Profit", "Region", "2", "Department", "107", "Staff", "Jim").Value
```

I expect it to display the data under Staff Jim in Cell C28 , but right now i can only get the data of all the staff under the same department of 107.

Comment: I usually add all the headers on rows, so there is no problem getting the result I want. But you must know that doing that it requires levels. The frist value on rows must always be taken (as a filter) then the second one and so on... Try it like that and see if it works.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what does it do instead?

Comment: @TimWilliams it will give me error 1004 (Application Defined or Object Defined Error)

Comment: @Damian if i put all the headers on rows it won't give me the data i want

Comment: Can you provide with a sample of your data?

Comment: @Damian there is a picture of the pivot table attached & i will add in the sample data now

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams man what's up with mine any idea?

Comment: No idea - can you share a workbook which reproduces the problem ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have just uploaded an answer with a code that works. Not sure why it works like that but god bless it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Adding Some Error Testing Code, The Code Finally Works.

````
Sub Test()

    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
    Set wkSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    wkSheet.Activate
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set PT = .PivotTables("PivotTable2")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C30").Select

    On Error Resume Next
.Cells(30, 5) = PT.GetPivotData("Profit", "Region", "5", "Department", "109", "Staff", "John").Value
'Your Line here which causes 1004 error
If Err.Number > 0 Then
  Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
End If

    End With

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

So like I've told you is as easy as taking all the filters to the rows like this:

[image: Pivot]

This way using this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim PT As PivotTable

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
        Set PT = .PivotTables("Test")

        .Cells(1, 1) = PT.GetPivotData("Profit", "Region", "2", "Department", "107", "Staff", "Jim").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Gave me the value of Jim's profit on cell A1 as you can see. Note that when you do this the filters have priority. In this case you **always** must filter for region, then department and finally Staff.

The order is irrelevant, but when you want to get staff data you must provide first both region and department.

When you want to get department data you only need to provide region and deparment. Lastly, if you only need data by region just provide de Region.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is there no way to do it with them in the columns?

Comment: It also worked on my end... the same way you have your data by columns. It's weird it doesn't on your sheet.

Comment: This code needs to be on a module. Are you using it on a module or the workbook itself @JoachimTan?

Comment: the code is on a module. Mind sharing a screenshot of your code screen?